# Unable to sync woocommerce variations

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm updating woocommerce variations programmatically. For the changes to be reflected we have to sync the products after updating values in the db.

I'm trying to do this by adding:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_variable_product_sync', $post_parent_id );
```

Unfortunately this is not working. I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '2007' not found or invalid function name in /wp-includes/plugin.php on line 524
```

2007 being my id in this case. I copied the do_action right from the docs. Do I need to implement a callback function? If so what would it have to do?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to first learn what it does do_action, add_action.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Comment: Hi and thanks. Since I'm a noob I'll just ask: are you saying I need to use add_action, not do_action?